# IP information for network attached epson scanner

Tags: networking, drivers, scanner

Where does the IP information about a network attached scanner get stored in the file system?

This is on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS (LSB Version: core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch)

I looked at /etc/sane.d/net.conf and /etc/sane.d/epson.conf and updated them with the correct IP but Xsane did not reach the scanner, until I used a vendor utility.

A little history:

I was trying to get my Epson ET-3760 printer/scanner to work as a scanner.  I went and got the package from http://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php and picked the Ubuntu/Debian version.  It came down fine and I installed it using the provided install.sh script.  But it didn't work when I went through "Show Applications" to find EpsonScan2.

Turns out I needed to install the following package:

```
sudo apt install libqt5widgets5
```

Then it would pop up a dialog with a pull down to select the scanner.
Unfortunately there was nothing in the list to select.  My printer is on a different network from the computer, so if it was attempting to discover the scanner via broadcast I was out of luck.

Eventually I happened to double click on the pull down presented by the "epsonscan2" command and it brought up another dialog to manually add the IP address of my scanner.

Now the vendor utility (epsonscan2) and both native utilities (xscanimage and Xsane) can reach the scanner, but I'd like to know where the configuration really is stored.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I was trying to ask where the IP address for a network scanner is stored in the configuration files /etc/something/xxxx.conf.  I was also trying to leave a little record of how I solved the problem for someone else who may stumble across their own version of this problem.  Specifically I am on LSB Version: core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS